# Alternative to onclick for select tag

Tags: javascript, html, select, dropdown

I have a Javascript `function` that changes a dropdown menu's options based on some `radio` buttons that have been selected. I originally had the `radio` buttons set to `onclick` to run the `function` but as it is based on 2 different sets of `radio` buttons this does not work. I changed the `onclick` to happen when the user selects the drop down however now you cannot `select` an actual `option` as it just resets the dropdown when a selection is made. Is there and alternative I can use?

```
Genotype <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown" onclick = "DROPDOWN(father);"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `onclick` you will need to track `onchange`, so even if there are some `label` elements around them, changing them, you will have your code working. As about the solution, you will need to implement a logic that determines the options to be generated upon any possible combination of your `radio` buttons. The code below is a proof-of-concept.

```js
function refreshOptions() {
    let innerHTML = "<option>Please select</option>";
    for (let item of document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]")) {
        if (item.checked) innerHTML += `<option value="${item.value}">${item.value}</option>`
    }
    document.getElementById("myselect").innerHTML = innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<select id="myselect">
    <option>Please select</option>
    <option value="foo1">foo1</option>
    <option value="bar1">bar1</option>
</select>
<label>foo1 <input onchange="refreshOptions()" type="radio" name="foo" value="foo1" checked></label>
<label>foo2 <input onchange="refreshOptions()" type="radio" name="foo" value="foo2"></label>
<label>bar1 <input onchange="refreshOptions()" type="radio" name="bar" value="bar1" checked></label>
<label>bar2 <input onchange="refreshOptions()" type="radio" name="bar" value="bar2"></label>
```